# Issue- save an image file to resource folder in iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, resources, uiimage

I am working on gallery kind of application. where user will tap image view to capture an image from camera. According to my requirement i need to save capture image in one specific folder in my device resource directory of the project. And that folder only i need to push on server. This is my code for capturing and writing into file...

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    CGFloat compression = 0.5f;

    UIImage *smallSizeImage = [self scaleImage:image toSize:CGSizeMake(140.0, 80.0)];
    imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(smallSizeImage, compression);

    ivPicture.image = smallSizeImage;

    self.passingSlPosition.positionImageId = [Util getNewGUID];

    [imageData writeToFile:[Util getFilePathForFileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg",self.passingSlPosition.positionImageId]] atomically:YES];

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(UIImage *)scaleImage:(UIImage *)image toSize:(CGSize)newSize
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

//Util class

```
+(NSString*)getFilePathForFileName:(NSString*)filename{

    NSString *cachePath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    return [cachePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
}

+ (NSString *)getNewGUID
{
    CFUUIDRef theUUID = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
    CFStringRef string = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, theUUID);
    CFRelease(theUUID);
    return (__bridge NSString *)string;
}
```

[image]
And After writing file , i am not able to see the file in resource using this path

~/Library/Application Support/iphone simulator....

Because I have not found the iphone simulator folder in Application Support.I have installed OS X 10.8.5 & Xcode-4.6.3.
So, can you please help me that what would be the following code for the above code? Please suggest some solution for this.

Thanks.

Comment: As per your question your unable to see iphone simulator, It may help for you to unhide hidden files and check http://www.mikesel.info/show-hidden-files-mac-os-x-10-7-lion/

Comment: The `~/Library` folder is hidden by default under OS X.

Comment: Why the long question and all of the code when all you wanted to know was how to access the `~/Library` folder on your Mac?

Comment: @rmaddyThanks..It's not like that, using the above code ..my image file is not saving in Application resource document. thats why i have attached my code, can u pls let me know is there any mistake in writing image file in resource.

Comment: Your code is saving the image in the `Library/Caches` folder within your app's sandbox.

Comment: Yes yes...it is storing in Library/Caches. Is it correct or it should show in application documents.

Comment: Thanks again @rmaddy.. u helped me before.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42913/discussion-between-anand-gautam-and-rmaddy)

Comment: @rmaddyr u there ? It is storing all the capturing image. Is it possible to save only final image in resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Command + Shift + G** in Finder. And input `~/Library`.
Then, you can access to Simulator folder.

Application Support -> iPhone Simulator

Comment: @JoeyThank you so much , now i got iphone simulator option.

Comment: @joeyBut inside my Application id documents there is no image file. Can you pls see my above code and let me know if there will be any mistake ?

Comment: First you should find your sandbox directory, and move to Library/Caches directory.

Comment: NSLog("%@", [Util getFilePathForFileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg",self.passingSlPosition.positionImageId]]);    in your imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: function.

Comment: @joeyThanks again ..pls check an attached screenshot. it is cuming in Library/Caches

Comment: After printing.. it is showing path in console which is    /Users/anandpmg/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/65DEFFCC-1C15-4B5E-B912-6802C24C4F28/Library/Caches/D6BEE7F3-2DA9-41BA-8A56-BB21B946A6AE.jpg

Comment: because getFilePathForFileName: function returns Caches directory. you may use NSDocumentDirectory instead of NSCachesDirectory.

Comment: @JoeyOk.. i will change it. But it is storing all the capturing image in application. Is it possible to save only final image in resource bcoz of memory?

Comment: @JoeyThanks alot for giving me time.. now all images are saving in documents resource folder instead of caches. Can we push that documents folder on server using php url ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42918/discussion-between-anand-gautam-and-joey)

Answer (score 0):

Try this open **Finder** then click **Go** in menu bar -> and click **option** button you can see hidden **Library** in the list -> select **Library** and you will find **Application Support** -> **iPhone Simulator**

Comment: Thanks @llyas.. now it is storing in caches. pls check above attached screenshots.

Comment: Try saving the image file in documents directory by specifying the path.

Comment: To save image to documents directory try this -

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *imgPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ImageName.jpg"];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

[imageData writeToFile:imgPath atomically:YES];

Comment: I have already saved my image files in document folder. But my problem is how can i send this folder to the server using php url ???

Comment: You need to send the images by converting it to base64 format by including in url or it depends on how your server will accept the image data it can accept json format as well.